# Complex Q Lookup

Tags: python, django

Here's the code,

```
user_obj = Q(first_name__icontains=query) | Q(last_name__icontains=query)
```

This looks for either first name or last name but if i'm searching for both at a time no results are shown.

How can I make a query for 'first name', 'last name' & also 'full name'?

Comment: ... If it's found in either of the first two then what's the difference?

Comment: @ IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Sir, In a search function, in case if user is typing the complete name. Given Answer is not working

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution (not ideal) would be to check for space in the query and split it considering first part as first name and remaining as last:

```
if ' ' in query:
    first_name, last_name = query.split(' ', 1)
else:
    first_name = query
    last_name = None

filters = Q(first_name__icontains=first_name)
if last_name:
    filters |= Q(last_name__icontains=last_name)

qs = User.objects.filter(filters)
```

Above solution is trying to find first name and last name using split approach if query contains a `space`, better solution would be parse name more intelligently, you could try [nameparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nameparser):

```
from nameparser import HumanName
name = HumanName(query)
first_name = name.first
last_name = name.last
# prepare Q objects as mentioned above
```

More better solution would be to use advanced search engines like Elasticsearch, Whoosh etc

Comment: Thank You so much Sir :) | I've chnaged "last_name = query" & it's querying for all three vales now ('first name', 'last name' & 'full name')

Comment: Sir what could be the ideal Solution for this?

Comment: I deliberately tried to not use `ideal` term :) but `Elasticsearch` would be a good candidate, it is more advanced though.

Comment: Thank You Sir :) Will see the Elasticsearch ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could construct the full name using `functions.Concat`, and then *annotate* a `full_name` field to your queryset which will be later used in the query provided by the `Q` object:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Concat
from django.db.models import CharField, Value as V

user_q_obj = Q(first_name__icontains=query) | Q(last_name__icontains=query) | \
             Q(full_name__icontains=query)

result = User.objects.annotate(
                   full_name=Concat(
                   'first_name', V(' '), 'last_name',
                   output_field=CharField()
                                           )).filter(user_q_obj)
```